# How to make left indent in text field after overflow in Jaspersoft studio

Tags: jasper-reports

I have defined an style in jaspersoft studio 6.4.3 which should move the lines, except the first line, 10 pix to the right.
The reason is that after text overflow in a text field, the second line appears beneath the first line with the same indent, but I need to change it for my table of content.
The following approach works fine by exporting in Java, but does not work after pdf export. In this case the box moves to right and the firstLineIndent has no effect.[image]

Here is the Style:

```
    <style name="Inhaltsverzeichnis" style="Formatvorlage Standard (kleiner) + 10 Pt." hTextAlign="Left" markup="styled" fontName="Calibri" isPdfEmbedded="true" >
    <box leftPadding="10"/>
    <paragraph firstLineIndent="-10"/>
</style>
```

And use it in my TOC:

```
        <band height="31" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{level} == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement style="InhaltsverzeichnisPunkte" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="1" width="440" height="18" uuid="b08b479c-10a8-4d87-8507-4f32fd50004f"/>
            <text><![CDATA[. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement style="InhaltsverzeichnisPunkte" x="396" y="1" width="45" height="18" uuid="bc43bd36-7466-457c-95e6-384410c05cbe"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["<style backcolor='white'>"+($V{PAGE_NUMBER} + $F{pageIndex} + 3)+"</style>"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor">
            <reportElement key="" style="Inhaltsverzeichnis" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="3" width="396" height="15" uuid="b19a02f7-3d3f-4086-86ed-5dc6859e5fd1"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["<style backcolor='white'>"+$F{label}+"</style>"]]></textFieldExpression>
            <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
```

[image]